# WPF ScrollViewer - Width and Height must be non-negative

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

Every now and again an app throws a 'width and height must be non-negative' error

```
Width and Height must be non-negative.
at System.Windows.Size..ctor(Double width, Double height)
at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Nothing changes (window size...) and it seems that it is caught outside the normal sub.. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: something inside the content must have changed, as you're inside the ScrollViewer's `OnLayoutUpdated` handler...  nothing inside your app is resizing dynamically and telling the scrollviewer to have negative viewport size or anything?

Comment: That's the odd thing - nowhere near anything that uses the scrollviewer when it throws the error!